# D3.js appending svg/dom element not working

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

So I'm trying to append a dom or svg element to a circle(the latter to avoid the foreign object thing). I'm doing this

```
        var tooltip  = d3.select(this).append("text")
            .attr("class", "tooltip")
            .text("HELLO")
            .attr('x', 1000)
            .attr('y', 1000);
```

Where this is the circle svg element.

However, this doesn't work -

[image]

But I can't see an effect on the webpage.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

In SVG, you can't append `text` element to `circle` elements -- the specification doesn't allow that. Append them to `g` elements or the top-level SVG, otherwise they won't be displayed.

Comment: so why does it show up in the DOM, but is not rendered?

Comment: Because the SVG specification doesn't allow the elements to be nested that way.

Comment: ah ok solved that. If I do this though  - svg.append("div").html(//retun somehtml).attr('x',1000).attr('y',1000) nothing is appended to the DOM

Comment: in other words how do I wrap the DOM element to be in SVG?

Comment: I've tried svg.append("g").append("div").html(function(){return some html}).attr('x', d3.event.pageX).attr('y', d3.event.pageY)

Comment: SVG doesn't have `div` elements. [This demo](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) should help with wrapping text.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to move or animate or locate some svg elements together, you need to create a group element and append all of those to the group.

```
<g>
   <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="green" />
   <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="20" fill="purple" />
</g>
```

then you can add attributes that goes for all of them:

```
<g stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="#fff">
```

and the "transform" is an available attribute too:

```
<g transform="translate(80,0)">
   <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="green" />
   <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="20" fill="purple" />
</g>
```

but if you're working with damn D3.js, you need to append it with svg namespace.

```
var tooltip  = d3.append('svg:g').append("svg:text")
            .attr("class", "tooltip")
            .text("HELLO")
            .attr('x', 1000)
            .attr('y', 1000);
tooltip.append('svg:circle').attr('fill','#f00');
```